# 8-ричная/8-я система счисления

Tags: орфография

Как правильно сделать наращение из *восьмеричная система счисления*? Верны какие варианты?

`8-я система счисления.`

`8-чная система счисления.`

`8-ричная система счисления.`

Comment: _8-я_ не подходит, т. к. подумается слово _восьмая_. По логике нужно 8-ричный, потому что всë, что идет после корня числительных, записывается через деыис как наращение. (Корень -ВОСЬМ- + _ричная_.)

Comment: Хотя «Грамота» рекомендует не сокращать. Вы уже задавали такой вопрос, но о слове _шестнадцатеричный_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Подобные прилагательные, напр.: *пятнадцареричный, шестеричный, десятеричный, восемнадцатеричный, восьмеричный*, — имеют одно основание — *ричный*, поэтому оно остается и в наращении: *15-ричный, 6-ричный, 10-ричный, 18-ричный, 8-ричный*.

В одном из ответов «Грамота» писала так:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Но всë-таки я нашëл ещë кое-что:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

То есть она всë-таки допускает такие написания.

В общем, пишем *8-ричный*.